# Android Studio IDE doesn't show profile picture after signing in with developer account

Tags: android-studio

As seen below, the IDE shows an image placeholder instead of my account profile image. It is supposed to be like this and not to load the profile picture?

If I remember correctly a few years ago it had my image.

[image: Profile picture missing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in `Android Studio Arctic Fox`.